# Curve Issue: Pinching with Bevel

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a way to avoid the pinching seen in images below? The object was created with curve circle, subdivided 2 points and deleted segment - then extruded to form the straight bit. Then added bevel for thickness. Less bevel will help but I need the larger value.
I did find that I can convert to mesh and do some topo tweaks but wondering if there is something to be done in the curve mode.
Thanks!
Daf
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you upload the blender file?

Comment: Sure - here is example file - thanks.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eKTWv_nKg4TZ3j0-4BemgxsMmRK3udjC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suspect that that is just a consequence of the bevel exceeding the initial radius. The only way I was able to beat the pinch was to increase the size of the main loop.

Comment: [you can scale them to fix pinch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVM4E.gif)

Comment: Hey thanks, Seyed, that does help! :)